# VBA Code to Search Text

Tags: vba, excel

I want to amend the code below

I want the findwhat to pick text from a range ("a1:20")-which contains the list of text i want to look for

If it finds the text in the description in B, i want it to return the text it found e.g jo IN range c beside its description

Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Sub x()
    Dim FindWhat, rngCell As Range, i As Integer

    FindWhat = Array("Jo", "oa", "of", "koo")
    For i = 0 To 3
        For Each rngCell In Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If InStr(rngCell, FindWhat(i)) <> 0 Then
                rngCell.Offset(0, 1) = rngCell
                rngCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Copy
            End If
        Next rngCell
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please try and explain again. I assume you're working in Excel? What version? What are you trying to do? How are you calling x()?

Comment: Yes-I am working in Excel 2003. Example-I have range a1:a20 which has a list of text Jo, ja, love, pizza etc I want to search for this in column b2:b400 (this has description). If i search for pizza in B2:B40- which it find it in any cell in b2:b400, i want to return the text it found in column c just right beside the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub x()
    Dim findRng As Range, _
        targetRng As Range, _
        findCell As Range, _
        found As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstFound As String, _
        columnName As String

    columnName = "B"
    Set findRng = Range("A1:A20")
    For Each findCell In findRng
        Set targetRng = Range(columnName & "2", Range(columnName & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        With targetRng
            Set found = .Find(findCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                firstFound = found.Address
                Do
                    found.Offset(0, 1).Value = found.Offset(0, 1).Value & findCell.Value & ", "
                    Set found = .FindNext(found)
                Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> firstFound
            End If
        End With
    Next findCell

End Sub
```

Note that unless what you're doing is a little more complex than this, you can achieve this result using cell formulae. Read the help on the Index, Match and VLookup functions to see how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks it works but more help needed- Say for example in column A1 boy a2 Girl a3 Cat - In column b1 I am a girl b2 i am a cat b3 I am a cat and dog I want the code to just pick the text in a beside b which it does presently but it seems to be copying it so many times and add IN. tHANKS

Comment: @user1649932 I've made an amendment to the code, try it again- see if it's closer to what you want. I've assumed you're capable of modifying it to remove the commas at the end, let me know if that's not the case. It might be a good learning exercise, however.

Comment: Hello-It works fine now! It was because I had boys 5 times in column A. Thanks a million, you are the best!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!111111

Comment: Thank you for all the exclamation marks and ones. Seriously though, just happy to have helped :)